# How to plot one component of a tensor?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, matlab-figure

My data is structured in the following way

```
v(1,1,:)=ones(10,1)
```

and using

```
plot(v(1,1,:))
```

results in the error

```
Error using plot Data may not have more than 2 dimensions
```

`size(v(1,1,:))` returns `[1 1 10]`. Shouldn't `v` be a 1D vector?

How should I plot the 3rd component of this tensor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singleton dimensions on the end are cut off automatically, so either [`permute`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) the third dimension to the first index, or use [`squeeze`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html):

```
plot(permute(v,[3 1 2]))
plot(squeeze(v(1,1,:)))
```